# How to debug Spring Security Oath2 and Jwt for knowing how it work

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2, jwt

I have successfully implemented Spring Boot Oath2 and Jwt in my Spring Boot Application. It work nice. Now i want know how it work, specially how it process access token when server receive any hit but to do that i'm unable to find the class in where i will put the break points because it handle all work internally. 
So to debug my application for knowing how it process every request from client, in where or in which class do in need to put break points? i can put break points inside my class which i created but that's not the scenery because Sprint Boot Oath2 and Jwt do that task internally by default, i need to put break in their.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to debug `/oauth/token` which generates the Access Token and Refresh Token you need to add a break point in `TokenEndpoint.postAccessToken` or `TokenEndpoint.getAccessToken` method based on Request Method type.

If you want to debug the process which validates the Access Token and Authenticates/Authorizes users then you need to add a break point in `OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter` method which responsible for extracting Access Token from `Authorization` header and authenticating/authorizing users.

Comment: i want to debug the process when i send a request to a restricted endpoint with bearer token and server start to verified that token, after verify that when give access to. That's the process i want to debug. So please could you specific the class names? because i'm unable to find in which class those beans or methods belongs. because there is a lot of beans in the spring boot app. thank you

Comment: You should look at second processing filter for that.

Comment: yeah i got that's but in which class or beans that filter belongs? because there lot of beans in the app, so i'm unable to find that specific beans.

Comment: also in Intellij IDEA there has no option to search for beans.

Answer (score 3):

You should add a break point in **spring.security.oauth2**
in **org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint** method **getAccessToken** and **postAccessToken**
and in **org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter** method **doFilter**
and also in
**org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.CheckTokenEndpoint** method **checkToken**